# eventClick with lightBox?

Tags: fullcalendar

How I can open lightBox in eventClick, I need init a lightBox whe I click in a event.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I actually ended up using fancybox and the way I managed to get it working was to use the **eventAfterRender** to bind it up.  I didn't have to do anything to the **eventClick** to prevent url follow, I think fancybox took care of that.  It didn't work when I performed this same wire up in the **eventClick** so you might want to follow this example with lightbox and see if that works for you as well.  Here is the relevant part of what I did.  Cheers!

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view ) { 
        if(event.url) {
            $('a',$(element)).fancybox({
                type: 'ajax'
            });
        }                    
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

eventClick documentation is located here: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/

Within the eventClick function you'll write code to display your lightBox.  Are you having any specific issues?  You're question is very general.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get this to work correctly.  Everytime I clicked on any link, not just events, it would display a lightbox.  I ended up using the event className attribute to set it to fancybox and that is working for me.

Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
            width: 1500,
            midWidth: 900,
            height : 800,
            minHeight: 600
        });
    });
</script>

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
          id: 2,
          className: \"fancybox fancybox.iframe\",
          title: 'Event 1',
          start: new Date(2013, 7, 12),
          url: '../sample.jsp'
        }
    ]
});
```