# FullCalendar: How to open event details in Colorbox?

Tags: fullcalendar, colorbox

I have created a jquery fullcalendar, pulling the feed from a google calendar and would like to open the event details in a colorbox.  So far, I am completely lost as to how to achieve this and am looking for help.  Everything that I have tried so far causes the calendar not to appear at all, so there is clearly a problem.  Here is the latest code that I have tried:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                events: {
                url: 'my feed url'
                }
                eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view ) { 
                    if(event.url) {
                        $('a',$(element)).colorbox({
                            type: 'ajax'
                        });
                    }                    
                }
            })

        });
</script>
```

I don't think I completely understand what's going on with fullcalendar's event information; so if someone can provide a working code that I can mess with, I would appreciate it. Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Comment: can you explain what exactly you are trying to achieve? eventAfterRender will be called for each event on the calendar on the page. Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: @aldrin - I would like to be able to click an event and have the event's details open in a colorbox, instead of linking back to the google site.  I don't think what you described is what I am expecting, I only used eventAfterRender, because I read it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378997/eventclick-with-lightbox.  If you have a solution that uses eventClick or something else, please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add the eventClick property when initializing the fullcalendar object and call colorbox  within,

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  editable: true,
  eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $.colorbox({html:"<h1>"+calEvent.title+"</h1><br><p>"+calEvent.start+" TO "+calEvent.end+"</p>"});
  },
  events: [
            {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: new Date(y, m, 1)
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
          end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
            }
          ]
});
```

This is a very basic example. You can expand on it as per your requirements. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for the start.  I altered it slightly to pull my Google Calendar feed, but after I click an event and the colorbox pops up, it navigates to the google url anyway.

Comment: are you getting any kind of javascript errors? what are y, m, d in the script? are they defined correctly?

Comment: I have y, m, & d defined as follows: `code` var d = date.getDate(); var m = date.getMonth(); var y = date.getFullYear(); `code`  I can only catch a glimpse of the info in the colorbox, but though the formatting seems off, the information seems to be accurate - before the page navigates to google.  I will open it with Firefox to use the developer toolbar to check for any javascript errors and get back to you.

Comment: I didn't get any javascript errors, but I noticed in the markup that each event has an href for the google url.  I guess I need to find a way to disable the default event click, so that it no longer generates that link.

Comment: I just ended up removing the code that generates the link from the gcal.js file - `code` $.each(entry.link, function(i, link) { if (link.type == 'text/html') { url = link.href; if (ctz) { url += (url.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'ctz=' + ctz; } } }); `code` I also had to add a pointer cursor to the css for that div.  Thanks so much for your help Aldrin!

Comment: To disable the default Google calendar link, add this to the eventClick function:
    jsEvent.preventDefault();